# How can I passing a list as argument in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Hi everyone I'm very new to the elixir, I'm trying to figure out how to pass a list as an argument in Elixir, what method should I use?

Comment: You just pass it in like any other argument: `example_function_call(example_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as all other argument function_name(argument)